# jquery simple ul li content slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I trying to make a super simple ul li *(content)* slider. My goal is to add a **prev** and **next** button.

Both buttons work fine, but my problem is with the sliding effect. The **next** sliding is very cool, but the **prev** button is not, and I can't figure it out how to make it like the **next** button sliding.

```js
$("ul li:gt(0)").hide();

$('#Next').click(function(){
  $('ul > li:first')
    .slideUp(1000)
    .next()
    .slideDown(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('ul');
});

$('#Prev').click(function(){
  $('ul > li:last')
    .slideDown(1000)
    .prev()
    .slideUp(1000)
    .end()
    .prependTo('ul');
  $("ul li:gt(0)").slideUp();
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>

<a id="Prev">Prev</a>
<a id="Next">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below. Add `$("ul li:gt(0)").slideUp(1000);`.

```js
$("ul li:gt(0)").hide();

$('#Next').click(function(){
  $('ul > li:first')
    .slideUp(1000)
    .next()
    .slideDown(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('ul');
});

$('#Prev').click(function(){
  $('ul > li:last')
    .slideDown(1000)
    .prev()
    .slideUp(1000)
    .end()
    .prependTo('ul');
$("ul li:gt(0)").slideUp(1000);
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>

<a id="Prev">Prev</a>
<a id="Next">Next</a>
```

Comment: @pedram now check it.